# object identifications in javascript and restful service

Tags: javascript, php, json, oop

Consider classes

```
Product = {
  variations: [],
  properties: []
}

Property = {
  values: []
}

Variation = {
  values: []
}

Value = {
  simpleString:""
}
```

On the client (in JS) I first create products with properties and the possible values each property may have.

After that I create variations. Each of them can have a set of several values. But it only can "use" the values, which do already exist for properties.

In the next step, I move that product-object over to rest api.

While in JS the values used in a variation points to the original object in the product property, after encoding to JSON and backwarts to stdClass in PHP behind the restful service, this link gets lost.

Of course I could give them IDs on my own and call them temp_id or so. Hacky.

How would pros do it?

---

PHP

I simply deserialize the incomming JSON `$object = json_decode($json);` and use RedBeans and Piped to manage that end. What it does is mainly just moving through the properties and create objects with `..._id == null` (then they get a unique ID).

Let's say I would do it manually:

I'd walk through the properties and store each value-object into the MySQL-db. Say

```
{
  value_id: null,
  simpleString: 'Green'
}
```

After storing it will have the `value_id = 111`.

Now I walk through the variations. One of these uses the Green-Value. But since this value will also be

```
{
  value_id: null,
  simpleString: 'Green'
}
```

how could I identify them? The string, of course, is too weak - no one could consider that. As mentioned above, I could give them temporary IDs. But surely there is a better way.

Comment: please post your php code

Comment: I'd go with the IDs. The JSON denotes values/object literals; it does not reference any other, "outer" objects - so yes, that link is broken.

Comment: Is the issue still unclear? Is there a pattern or so? How do you solve this pointing-to-issue in general?

Comment: Nobody did ever face that situation?